# Why "key in myObject" does not narrow the type if key is of type string?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

I don't understand this:

```
const VALUES = {
  name: "name",
  age: "age",
  address: "address",
};

export function getVal(key: string) {
  if (key in VALUES) {
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; age: string; address: string; }'.
//  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; age: string; address: string; }'.ts(7053)
    return VALUES[key];
  }

  return "";
}
```

The conditional is explicitly making the `key` be one of the keys in `VALUES` in the true branch. So why is typescript complaining? Wouldn't `key in obj` narrow `key` to be one of the keys in `obj`?

I understand I can do one of two things to fix it:

A/

```
const VALUES: { [index: string]: string } = {
  name: "name",
  age: "age",
  address: "address",
};
```

B/

```
export function getVal(key: keyof typeof VALUES) {
  ...
}
```

But what if I want to keep `VALUES` type constrained to those keys, and/or the `key` param remain as a `string`?

EDIT:

As T.J. Crowder pointed out in the comments, perhaps a better "fix" would be:

```
const VALUES = {
  name: "name",
  age: "age",
  address: "address",
};

function isValidKey(key: string): key is keyof typeof VALUES {
  return key in VALUES;
}

export function getVal(key: string) {
  if (isValidKey(key)) {
    return VALUES[key];
  }

  return "";
}
```

Comment: The third thing you could do to fix it: a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). But I get that that's not the question. :-) (Or at least, I don't think it is.)

Comment: `in` keyword also includes the builtin properties of whatever you're comparing. I.e. `.toString()` etc. That's why it's not matching. Do `VALUES.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Comment: @Joel - `hasOwnProperty` won't narrow the type of `key` either, but you're right about the issue with `in`.

Comment: "Why" questions are really tricky on Stack Overflow. Fundamentally, it doesn't narrow `key` because the TypeScript team have decided it's best not to do that. The documentation for [`in` narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) specifically says that the left-hand operand has to be a *string literal*, not just a string. It doesn't say *why*. There might be an explanation in a github issue...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh yeah, you're right. I jumped the gun there. `key: keyof typeof VALUES` is Probably the better approach here IMO.

Comment: The closest I can get to an authoritative answer here is that it is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284) and it hasn't been implemented yet.  Other than the fact that they have never gotten around to it, or that it might not be easy to implement and have it perform well, it would be unsound in general to do this since objects can have more properties than TS knows about (which is why `Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]` and not `(keyof typeof obj)[]`).

Comment: Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer, if not, what am I missing? OP, please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply.

Comment: @jcalz sounds good, seems like the proper answer

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript supports [narrowing via `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), **but currently a check like `key in obj` will only serve to narrow the type of `obj` and not the type of `key`.**  Traditionally this would only work when `obj` was of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and then `"k" in obj` would filter the union to just those members with a known `k` key.  TypeScript 4.9 [added additional narrowing for non-union types `in`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#in-narrowing); so if `obj` is not a union, `"k" in obj` will narrow `obj` to a type where `obj.x` is an `unknown` property.  Neither of these narrowings do anything to `key` given a `key in obj` check.

The reason this doesn't already happen is because it was never implemented. **There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284)** asking to narrow the type of `key`.  It's marked as "Awaiting more feedback", so it is unlikely to get implemented unless there's more engagement on the issue, with  and descriptions of use cases, and why the current workarounds are not acceptable.